# How to clean bundle from duplicate or unused entries?

Tags: netbeans, bundle

In a Netbeans project I have a bundle with about 3000 entries: most of them are unused or duplicated.
I can clean it by hand but it will take an year or two...

I searched for a solution but I found only [this article about bundlizer](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/clean_property_file.html?print=yes), proposed in different sites. Unfortunately all links are broken so I cannot download that software, besides it is old and it is not maintained. There is also a long linux command which shuold clean the bundle, but definitely it is not easy to understand...

Can you suggest an alternative way ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this code was abandoned and dropped when NetBeans migrated their repository to Mercurial.

That long Linux pipe can help you identify some keys from you bundle. The idea is to parse keys from bundle file and then 'grep' all your sources to check if it is used there (preferably as String literal - surrounded by quotes). You will have to check the output for false signals. And some keys can be spotted in commented blocks but at least it is an approximation.